# LSTM time series forecasting, predictions stabilize

Tags: r, lstm, prediction, forecasting

My code is in R using the Keras and Tensorflow libraries. I'm creating an LSTM model to forecast 100 future values. My input shape is (100,200,1).

Let's say my input data is X. I make a prediction at time step t=201 and get the column Y of predictions. Then I create Xnew = c(X[2:200],Y) a new variable where I concatenate X (except for the first column) and Y. I use this Xnew to predict the next time step.

What's happening is that, after a certain number of predicted future time steps (around 15), the predictions become constant for each time step afterwards. Does anyone know why this happens?

```
prdvec = function(dat,modname, numpreds, cnt, scl){

  model = load_model_hdf5(modname)

  inpt = dat
  pred = list()

  for(i in 1:numpreds){
    pred[[i]] <- predict(model, reshape_X_3d((inpt[,1:ncol(inpt)]-cnt)/scl), batch_size = 1)
    inpt = cbind(inpt[,2:ncol(inpt)],(pred[[i]]*scl+cnt))
    print(i)
    flush.console()
  }

  pred
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter a similar problem. Maybe when the LSTM units take into input created by itself, it tends to stabilize.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should add more information to your answer or write it as a comment.